How to create a TextAnnotation on a rotated PDF page using iText7 in C#?
I am trying to create a TextAnnotation in a rotated PDF page using iText7 in C#. The annotation is created in the right place, but the text is not shown. Here is my code:
string src = "36x24_Rot_90.pdf";
string dest = "output.pdf";
string text = "This is a text annotation";

PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfPage page = pdfDoc.GetFirstPage();

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(300, 300, 200, 50);
PdfTextAnnotation annotation = new PdfTextAnnotation(rect);
annotation.SetContents(text);

PdfFormXObject xObject = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(rect.GetWidth(), rect.GetHeight()));
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(xObject, pdfDoc);

PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(iText.IO.Font.Constants.StandardFonts.HELVETICA);
float fontSize = 12;
float textWidth = font.GetWidth(text, fontSize);
float textHeight = fontSize;

// Keep the text upright despite page rotation
canvas.ConcatMatrix(0, 1, -1, 0, rect.GetWidth(), 0);

// Add text to the appearance
canvas.BeginText();
canvas.SetFontAndSize(font, fontSize);
canvas.SetFillColor(ColorConstants.BLACK);
canvas.MoveText(rect.GetWidth() / 2 - textHeight / 2, rect.GetHeight() / 2 - textWidth / 2);
canvas.ShowText(text);
canvas.EndText();

PdfDictionary appearanceDict = new PdfDictionary();
appearanceDict.Put(PdfName.N, xObject.GetPdfObject());
annotation.SetAppearance(PdfName.N, xObject.GetPdfObject());

page.AddAnnotation(annotation);
pdfDoc.Close();


I have tried to set the appearance stream and rotate the text properly, but it seems the text still does not appear on the PDF.
My questions are:
How can I make the text visible in the annotation?
Is there something wrong with the way I am creating and applying the appearance stream?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
